# Proving that the Lebesgue extension of any measure m is complete

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I feel like the answer is right in front of me for this one, but for some reason I can't quite figure it out.

The questions ask us to prove that the Lebesgue extension of any measure $m$ is complete.

We are given the definition: A measure $\mu$ is said to be complete if every subset of a set of measure zero is measurable (i.e. if $A'\subset A$, $\mu(A)=0$ implies $A'\in \varphi_\mu$,) where $\varphi_\mu$ is the system of all measurable sets with $\sigma$-additive measure $\mu$.

I also know that If $A'\subset A$ and $\mu(A)=0$, then $\mu^*(A')=0$. And since the empty set, $\emptyset \in R(\varphi_m)$ then $\mu^*(A'\bigtriangleup \emptyset) = \mu^*(A')=0$.

Comment: What is the definition of the Lebesgue extension of $m$?

Comment: Previously in the text book (Introductory Real Analysis - Kolmogorov and Fomin) they introduce the definition of measure on an elementary set A as the summation of of the measure of rectangles $P_k$ that make up A. Then they introduce the idea of ring and semi-ring and the extension of measure from a semi-ring to the ring generated by a semi-ring. But then they just state "As before the sigma-additive measure $\mu$ on the system $\varphi_\mu$ of all measurable sets is called the Lebesgue extension of the original measure $m$.

Comment: But I think this is where some of my confusion is coming from

Comment: I see. You construct an outer measure $\mu^\ast$, and the restriction of $\mu^\ast$ to the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu^\ast$-measurable sets is the Lebesgue extension. So what you have to show is that every set $A$ with $\mu^\ast(A) = 0$ is $\mu^\ast$-measurable. Look at the definition of $\mu^\ast$-measurability. It is not hard to deduce from that. Recall that outer measures are monotonic [$B\subset C \implies \mu^\ast(B) \leqslant \mu^\ast(C)$].

Comment: ok. Thanks so much :)